# Google Cloud Project : Access Issues

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-search-console

I created a Google Cloud Project for using Google Search Console API in App Script to fetch data into my linked Google Sheet. It is working fine by my email. I wanted it to be usable by a list of users with a specific domain. I assigned the domain in IAM & Admin settings with Edit Role. But the users are still unable to edit or access the project. (They need access to set the project ID after copying the Google Sheet to make it function properly or if there is any way to set up a Project ID automatically upon copying a Google Sheet, that would be better.)

Note: I verified that it is working fine on whitelisted Gmail accounts with editor roles.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to set up a project ID automatically, However, you can create a script that the users can run to set up the project ID after copying the  Google Sheet.

Comment: I tried setting this up with script but that did not work either.
Other than that, any ideas on why am I getting access errors even after adding a domain on IAM & Admin?

Comment: @AmnaIrfan make sure users have accepted the invitation or requests for access to the project, secondly are sure users are using the correct email to get access they should use company email address instead of personal

Comment: for setting up a Project ID automatically upon copying on Google Sheets. Use Google Apps scripts to create new projects a generate unique project ID for each new copy of Google sheet.' Project. creates' method in the Google Cloud Resource Manager API it will allow to create of new projects programmatically and assign it a unique ID then you can use it in your script @AmnaIrfan further this documentation helps you to understand https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects